# Hibernate Criteria / Oracle - Join - Return only if all associated data match conditions

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have the following (approximate) SQL Schema:

```
brand         model        equipment
brand_id      model_id     equipment_id
brand_name    model_name   equipment_nickname
                           equipment_brand_id
                           equipment_model_id
```

Then I have a N-N relation between a equipment and a equipment group, like so:

```
equipment <----> equipment_equipment_group <----> equipment_group
```

So, a equipment can belong to different groups and all the shebang.

Thing is, the filtering conditions to this thing is kinda strange to me. I only will return any conditions if **every** equipment in the group fills up the conditions.

For example: I can have 10 Brand X and 20 Brand Y equipments in on a group. On another group I only have 30 Brand  Y equipments. If I filter my equipments by Brand Y, only the second group will be filtered, because every equipment in it meet my criteria.

I am building this with Hibernate Criteria, but I would be more than happy to see the SQL for this too, no need to know Java on this one.

So, is this doable ?

Comment: Do you want an answer in SQL?

Comment: @GordonLinoff SQL or JPA Criteria, whatever suits you best. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with a `having` clause:

```
select eeg.equipment_equipment_group
from equipment_equipment_group eeg join
     equipment e
     on eeg.equipment_id = e.equipment_id
group by eeg.equipment_equipment_group
having sum(case when e.equipment_model_id <> 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause is counting the cases where the equipment model is not in your list.  The `= 0` says there are no cases where this happens.

I left out some of the extra joins (to `brand` and `model`) to focus on the logic.

Comment: I think it may work! What if I need to add the other joins ? How should I update my HAVING clause ? For example, If I want to filter by model AND brand ?

Comment: @GustavoRamos . . . It would be the same logic with additional clauses connected by `AND`.

Comment: makes perfect sense... shame on me. Well, I have the excuse of being 1am already here. :) I'll test this first thing tomorrow morning and will let you know the results. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to check the condition for a group first and then check if the total result for that group equals the total number of products in the group. Something like :

```
SELECT * FROM equipment
INNER JOIN equipment_equipment_group ON 
  equipment_equipment_group.equipment_id = equipment.equipment_id 
INNER JOIN equipment_group ON 
  equipment_equipment_group.equipment_group_id = equipment_group.equipment_group_id
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, equipment_equipment_group.equipment_group_id FROM equipment 
   INNER JOIN equipment_equipment_group ON 
     equipment_equipment_group.equipment_id = equipment.equipment_id 
   WHERE 
     -- Whatever conditions
     equipment.equipment_brand_id = 1
   GROUP BY
     equipment_equipment_group.equipment_group_id) AS equip_match ON 
  equipment_equipment_group.equipment_group_id = equip_match.equipment_group_id AND
  -- Only if then nb of equipment returned by subquery equals the total number of equipment in the group
  equip_match.cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM equipment_equipment_group as eqg WHERE eqg.equipment_group_id = equip_match.equipment_group_id)
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e13f0/1) in MySQL.